# How to Count and Group Geohash Values in InfluxDB V2 Using Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm working on a project where I need to display locations on a map grouped by Geohash values. I'm struggling with writing a query to show Geohash values, group them, and count the occurrences within each group.

Here's a sample of the data I have inserted into InfluxDB:

```
geoip2influx,type=geomaphash City="Jakarta",Count=2,Country_code="ID",Country_name="Indonesia",Geohash="qqt4fxmz",Host="Server-1",Ip="203.12.34.56",Latitude="-6.2088",Longitude="106.8456"
geoip2influx,type=geomaphash City="Jakarta",Count=2,Country_code="ID",Country_name="Indonesia",Geohash="qqt4fxmz",Host="Server-1",Ip="203.12.34.56",Latitude="-6.2088",Longitude="106.8456"
geoip2influx,type=geomaphash City="Jakarta",Count=2,Country_code="ID",Country_name="Indonesia",Geohash="qqt4fxmz",Host="Server-1",Ip="203.12.34.56",Latitude="-6.2088",Longitude="106.8456"
geoip2influx,type=geomaphash City="Jakarta",Count=2,Country_code="ID",Country_name="Indonesia",Geohash="qqt4fxmz",Host="Server-1",Ip="203.12.34.56",Latitude="-6.2088",Longitude="106.8456"
```

I'm using Grafana to query the data with the following Flux query:

```
from(bucket: "geoip2influx")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "geoip2influx")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Geohash" )
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop", "_measurement", "type"])
  |> group(columns: ["_value"])
```

[image]

My expected:

| Geohash | Count |
| --- | --- |
| qqt4fxmz | 3 |

So I can use the field Geohash and Count into Geohash Field and Size Field
[image]

I'm looking for guidance on how to modify my query to effectively count and group Geohash values.

My Grafana and InfluxDB environment details are as follows:

- Grafana version: 10.1.4
- Data source type & version: InfluxDB 2.0.4
- OS Grafana is installed on: Docker
- User OS & Browser: Ubuntu 20.04 & Chrome
- Grafana plugins: Geomap

Answer (score 0):

to use the "groupBy()" function in Flux, it needs to import the "experimental" package at the beginning of query. query should look like this:

```
import "experimental"

    from(bucket: "geoip2influx")
      |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "geoip2influx")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Geohash") 
      |> groupBy(columns: ["Geohash"])
      |> count()
      |> yield(name: "count")
```

Please make sure to also include the "experimental" package in the list of required packages when creating a new Flux query in the InfluxDB UI Data Explorer.

Comment: I have tried, but unfortunately, got an error: 
Status: 500. Message: invalid: error @5:6-5:13: undefined identifier groupBy

Comment: are you importing the "experimental" package?

Comment: I have tried the query in InfluxDB UI’s Data Explorer.

Comment: Make sure to select "Flux" as the query language and include the "experimental" package.

Comment: Yes, I did. but got an error: Status: 500. Message: invalid: error @5:6-5:13: undefined identifier groupBy https://shorturl.at/juAB5

Comment: check update answer, if you did same still got it, can you instead update question and include the full code

Comment: if still doesnt work, "pivot()" function can be tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255583/discussion-between-iamyusuf-and-afzal-k).